# How to set patchvalue for angular formarray

Tags: angular, formarray, patchvalue

In my angular application I have a FormArray inside my FormGroup. I get some values which is an array and I need form control to patchValue with the array.
When I do that, I see only one value attached to the formArray. Remaning are not set.

I tried to set  :

```
form.controls['mycarsform']?.patchValue(formVal.mycarsform);
 form.controls['mycarsform']?.get('mycarsGroup.carArrayGroupForm').patchValue(formVal.mycarsform?.mycarsGroup.carArrayGroupForm);
```

Below is my formGroup:

mycarsform : formGroup
controls:
mycarsGroup : formGroup
controls :
carArrayGroupForm : FormArray
controls :
formGroup:
controls
invoiceAmt : FormControl
type:   FormControl
company : FomrControl

Below is my formVal which has values for carArrayGroupForm

```
formVal :

mycarsform :
    mycarsGroup:
        carArrayGroupForm :
            [
             {                              invoiceAmt = '1800.00'
                                type = 'Benz"
                                company : 'Bmw'},
            {                               invoiceAmt '1200.00'
                                type = 'Hyundai'
                                company = 'Ford'}
             ]
```

Comment: Please format code indent, provide the code that is debuggable. Thanks.